# Underscore each method returning values

Tags: jquery, underscore.js

This is a stripped down example of what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to get my wrapper function `myElements` to return the elements coming from the underscore each iterator. I can trace out the values of the els inside the `_.each` function but how can I get my function to return those values when called from my `buttonClickListener`?

```
buttonClickListenr: function(event){

    if ( $(event.target).is( myElements() )) return;
    ..// otherwise move on in my event phase

}

myElements: function(){
    var filter=['a','b'];
    _.each(filter, function(el){ 
        return el
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do doesn't really make sense. The 'include' operator is probably more useful for you:

`if ( _(filter).include($(event.target)) ){ return; }`

Answer (score 1):

The `each` function will invoke the callback once per element and not group the return values as you expect.  Instead you need to store them in a structure which persists after the `each` method finishes

Try the following

```
getNums: function(){
  var filter=['20','2'];
  var result = [];
  _.each(filter, function(num){ 
    result.push(num);
  });
  return result;
}
```

**EDIT**

OP clarified they just want to see if the `event.target` is in the array.  In that case you just want to use the `indexOf` method.  For example

```
getNums: function() {
  return ['20', '2'];
},

buttonClickListener: function(event){
  if (this.getNums().indexOf(event.target) >= 0) {
    // It's present
  }
}
```

Comment: Right but this returns an arry of the numbers. I want to be able to call this in a if ( bla.is( getNums() ) ...do something.    So I want to be able to use the returned value one by one to check with the is method.

Comment: @Chapsterj it's really unclear what you want this function to do then.  Could you try giving a larger example?

Comment: why not `if ( getNums.length > 0 ) {...` ?

Comment: Ok updated my post with a more functional example. sorry for not being more clear what I need to do.

Comment: @Chapsterj i still don't understand. What exactly are you trying to test?

Comment: I'm trying to test if the event.target is equal to any of the elements in the returning array from the myElements method. The problem is nothing gets returned from the myElements() method.